# react shows strange array / object proptype error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I do this

```
AdminDashboard.propTypes = {
  users: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
```

I got this warning from react

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop users of type array supplied to AdminDashboard, expected object.
```

Then I changed to

```
AdminDashboard.propTypes = {
  users: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};
```

I got this

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `users` of type `object` supplied to `AdminDashboard`, expected `array`.
```

What do you want, react?

Update:

My users look like this

```
[{
    "_id": "5904176e9ca7649b1eae",
    "name": "Ching",
    "university": "Havard",
    "member_since": "2017-04-29T04:14:09.545Z",
}]
```

Comment: Please put code of component that passes users to this component. Then only it is possible to help

Comment: Its not possible to give you perfect insight looking at these pieces of code. There are many possibilities. Make sure you always pass `array` as the prop. If your users are coming from some API call make sure that till the API is not available and the component is initialized, users is set to an empty array`[]` and not `{}` or `undefined`

Comment: How are you getting `users`? Is it from an API request?

Comment: somewhere you are passing array and object for your component, without looking at the code exactly we can't tell where this is happening!